# When to use $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ vs $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ to find the slope of the tangent line

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

I was given 2 formulas but I am unsure of when to use each one. Both of them got the same answer for a given question

> Find the slope of tangent at $x = 2$ for the function $y = 2x^2$

Formula 1:
$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x - a}$$
Formula 2:
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h}$$

Answer 1:
$$\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = 8$$
Answer: 2
$$\lim_{h \to 0} f(x) = 8$$

My question is:

> What is the difference between the two answers/formulas? And when should I be using each method?

Comment: Short answer: you can use whichever you like, whenever you want. The two formulae are logically equivalent, so you can use whichever you find easier in the given circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same formula, except for a shift in the limiting variable. Specifically, if you let $x = a+h$, then both are the same, since $$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{a+h \to a} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{(a+h)-a} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

I prefer to use the second formula (with $h$) almost always. I find it easier to find a general derivative as well using this one, but it is up to your personal preference about which one to use.

Comment: Thanks. Most youtube videos I've seen seem to use the second one as well.

Comment: I am going to assume that the second formula is also used more frequently when finding the average rate of change?

Comment: @RudyGoburt You wouldn't use either of these to find the average rate of change. They are used to find the instantaneous rate of change (i.e. the derivative).

Answer (score 0):

I always found this example enlightening. Let $f(x)=\sin(x)$, then Formula 1 gives
$$f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(a)}{x-a}.$$
First thoughts are you could try Taylor series, which seems very messy. I also thought about perhaps "reverse engineering" $$\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\sin(y)\cos(x)\tag{1}$$ but that doesn't seem obvious either.

But if we try Formula 2,
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(h)\cos(x)+\sin(x)\cos(h)-\sin(x)}{h},$$
then things look a bit more straightforward since we cam stick to working with limits and show that $\sin(h)/h\to 1$ and $(\sin(x)\cos(h)-\sin(x))/h\to 0$.

As the previous answer says, they are equivalent and one version may be easier to work with than the other, depending on preference.

Comment: It also helps to use$$\frac{\sin x-\sin a}{x-a}=\operatorname{sinc}\tfrac{x-a}{2}\cos\tfrac{x+a}{2}\stackrel{x\to a}{\to}\cos a.$$

Comment: @J.G. that's a good one too.