# Clarification on the definition of derivative/differentiablility

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I'm having a hard time understanding where to use:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

My textbook seems to use either one of these in similar exercises and from what I've tried they produce the same result. Any help?

Comment: Algebraically, one method may be less tedious depending on the type of function $f$.

Comment: They are the same thing. What textbook are you using?

Comment: @mrsamy some crappy textbook without any graphs and skipping huge chunks of equations for the sake of cramming as much exercises as possible in a page by a professor of our school. Really not helpful at all.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3866391/42969.

Comment: Sometimes in evaluating limits, you can write the given function in a "derivative form". The derivative taken at that point (at which you want to take the limit) will then give you the answer. For these problems, the first notation is algebraically easier to work with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either one, they mean the same thing.  To see this, we can start with $$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$ and set $h = x - a$.  Then we can say that $x\to a\implies h\to 0$, so we can make the substitution $x = a+h$: $$\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h) - f(a)}{h}.$$

Comment: The teacher told us that we use h->0 when we want to find the derivative of a function at a specific point, and we use x->a when we wanna find the derivative of the whole function. That kinda didn't make sense to me. Anyway thanks a lot +1

Answer (score 1):

They are the same expression under the condition $x=a+h$:
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{a+h\to a}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{a+h-a}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}.
$$
Thus it is equivalent to use either one!